# resizable 2d floor plan , ruler on drag images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, floor

I am searching for interactive 2d floor plan with following feature

[image]

that means user can drag and resize the floor map on the same time .
only relative link i have found is

Edit : till now i have been able to create svg based diagram and applied anchor 
to drag image

[image]

my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sbh24vuq/

```
 $(function() {

          addBackdrop(50);

          var $window = $(window);
          var radius = 40, editColor = 'rgb(79, 128, 255)';
          var type = /(canvas|webgl)/.test(url.type) ? url.type : 'svg';
          var two = new Two({
              type: Two.Types[type],
              fullscreen: true,
              autostart: true
            }).appendTo(document.body);


         ....
complete code is on fiddle 
        }
```

but i would like to add ruler in while dragging .

Comment: If you think this is just going to be an easy task, if you're not familiar with JavaScript Canvas, think again. I can write the code, but I'd want to get paid for that.

Comment: i have found many articles in html5 canvas and found anchor drag features which resembles most . but I am not getting exactly something like this

Comment: That's why you hire professionals. It will take you between 4 to 6 years experience to do the job at a half decent pace.

Comment: any solution ?      ..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo . You should probably have at least a basic understanding of Trigonometry and full knowledge of the JavaScript Canvas API. Of course, this requires your ability to understand and create Event Driven JavaScript.

Comment: i created fiddle based on some research , now remaining thing is just wanted to create 2 rectangle images and add ruler

Comment: Hey you are able to get solution for this ? I want to implement same thing like [this](https://www.wanaplan.com/try_plan)

Answer (score 7):

Start with exploring existing open source floor plan projects out there:

- https://github.com/topics/floorplan?l=javascript
- https://github.com/topics/floorplans?l=javascript

Here's what a quick search reveals:

- [react-planner](https://github.com/cvdlab/react-planner)
- [Floor Plan V4](https://github.com/allnash/d3-v4-floorplan)
- [homeRoughEditor](https://github.com/ekymoz/homeRoughEditor)

After that you'd want to check out it's features by going to demo pages:

- [react-planner demo](https://cvdlab.github.io/react-planner/)
- [homeRoughEditor demo](http://homerougheditor.zipl.io/)

Next, you'd delve into code and try to make sense of how it's implemented.